# Discerning how to transform plane B to plane A from how to transform plane A to plane B

Tags: matrices, vectors, coordinate-systems

I'm working on an existing VB6 application which uses a 3 coordinate systems to represent the points on a profile curve for a worm gear.

I've put together the diagram below to try and illustrate the coordinate planes I'm working with:

- G ($X_g$, $Y_g$, $Z_g$) represents the global/axial coordinate system.
- N ($X_n$, $Y_n$, $Z_n$) represents the normal coordinate system.

There is also an axial coordinate system A (Xa, Ya, Za) that is equivalent to G (Xg, Yg, Zg) because they both represent the worm part.

The worm part looks something like the figure below:

[image: ZN worm part diagram]

I have put together the following diagram to try and illustrate how these coordinate systems are related:

[image: Coordinate systems diagram]

The sides of the worm profile are perpendicular to the line shown in this diagram as "Zc" and I already have code that calculates a point in the "G" coordinate system that is equivalent to a point in the "N" coordinate system using the the following parameters:

- Profile point ($X_n$, $Z_n$)
- Lead (L) - this is the linear distance travelled when a point on the
  worm moves by 1 revolution
- Normal plane angle ($\phi$) - this is the angle between the $X_g$ and
  $X_n$ axes
- Axial point ($X_a$, $Z_a$)

In this case, $Y_n = Y_a = 0$.

This converts a point on the normal coordinate system ($X_n$, $Y_n$, $Z_n$) to the axial coordinate system ($X_g$, $Y_g$, $Z_g$) via matrix transformations using the following operations:

$XYZN = \begin{bmatrix}
X_n \\ 
0 \\ 
Z_n \\ 
sin \theta_n \\
0 \\
-cos \theta_n
\end{bmatrix}$

$XYZG = \begin{bmatrix}
(cos \Phi \cdot XYZN_{[1,1]}) \\ 
(sin \Phi \cdot XYZN_{[1,1]}) \\ 
XYZN_{[1,3]} \\
(cos \phi \cdot XYZN_{[2,1]}) \\
(sin \phi \cdot XYZN_{[2,1]}) \\
XYZN_{[2,3]}
\end{bmatrix}$

$\beta = tan^{-1} \frac{ XYZG_{[1,2]} }{ XYZG_{[1,3]} }$

$\beta$ is the angle to rotate to the coordinate system where Y = 0.

$XYZA = \begin{bmatrix}
(XYZG_{[1,1]} + (L \cdot (\beta / 2\pi))) \\ 
(XYZG_{[1,2]} \cdot cos \beta - XYZG_{[1,3]} \cdot sin \beta) \\ 
(XYZG_{[1,2]} \cdot sin \beta - XYZG_{[1,3]} \cdot cos \beta) \\
XYZG_{[2,1]} \\
(XYZG_{[2,2]} \cdot cos \beta - XYZG_{[2,3]} \cdot sin \beta) \\
(XYZG_{[2,2]} \cdot sin \beta - XYZG_{[2,3]} \cdot cos \beta)
\end{bmatrix}$

$\alpha = tan^{-1} (L \div (2\pi \cdot XYZA_{[1,3]}))$

$\alpha$ is the lead angle of the worm curve.

$HTAN = \begin{bmatrix}
-sin \alpha \\ 
cos \alpha \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

$tanXYZA = \begin{bmatrix}
XYZA_{[2,1]} \\ 
XYZA_{[2,2]} \\ 
XYZA_{[2,3]}
\end{bmatrix}$

$ANORMAL = tanXYZA \cdot HTAN$

Calculate the axial plane point:

$X_a = XYZA_{[1,1]}$

$Z_a = XYZA_{[1,3]}$

I have managed to put together the following to perform the transformation between the "G" and "N" coordinate systems:

$XYZA = \begin{bmatrix}
X_A \\ 
0 \\ 
Z_A \\ 
sin \theta_A \\ 
0 \\ 
-cos \theta_A
\end{bmatrix}$

$CPHI = cos \phi$

$SPHI = sin \phi$

$XYZG = \begin{bmatrix}
CPHI & SPHI & 0 \\ 
-SPHI & CPHI & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot XYZA = \begin{bmatrix}
(CPHI \cdot XYZA_{[1]} + (SPHI \cdot XYZA_{2})) \\ 
-(SPHI \cdot XYZA_{[1]}) + (CPHI \cdot XYZA_{2})\\ 
XYZA_{[3]} \\ 
(CPHI \cdot XYZA_[4]) + (SPHI \cdot XYZA_{[5]})) \\ 
-(SPHI \cdot XYZA_[4] + (CPHI \cdot XYZA_{[2]})]) \\ 
XYZA_{[6]}
\end{bmatrix}$

$\beta = tan^{-1} (XYZG_{[2]} \div XYZG_{[3]})$

$CB = cos \beta$

$SB = sin \beta$

$XYZN = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & CB & SB \\ 
0 & -SB & CB
\end{bmatrix} \cdot XYZG = \begin{bmatrix}
(XYZG_{[1]} - (L \cdot \beta \div 2\pi))\\ 
(XYZG_{[2]} \cdot CB) - (XYZG_{[3]} \cdot SB)\\ 
-(XYZG_{[2]} \cdot SB) + (XYZG_{[3]} \cdot CB)\\ 
XYZG_{[4]} \\ 
(XYZG_{[5]} \cdot CB) - (XYZG_{[6]} \cdot SB)\\ 
-(XYZG_{[5]} \cdot SB) + (XYZG_{[6]} \cdot CB) 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\alpha = tan^{-1} (L \div (2\pi \cdot XYZN_{[3]}))$

$\alpha$ is the lead angle between the X axis and the worm helix.

$HTAN = \begin{bmatrix}
-sin \alpha \\ 
cos \alpha \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

$tanXYZA = \begin{bmatrix}
XYZN_{[4]} \\ 
XYZN_{[5]} \\ 
XYZN_{[6]}
\end{bmatrix}$

$ANORMAL = tanXYZA \cdot HTAN$

$X_n = XYZN_{[1]}$

$Z_n = XYZN_{[3]}$

I have done some initial testing using the following points:

Original $P_n = (X_n = -2.37094747375275, Z_n = 8.46070725643985)$

I converted this to its equivalent on the "A" coordinate system using the existing code.

- Lead (L) = 14.311 mm
- Normal Plane Angle ($\phi$) = 20.14 degrees
- $P_a = (X_a = -2.44506210634239, Z_a = 8.5)$

The resulting point I get is as follows:

$P_{n'} = (X_{n'} = -2.52041193480879, Z_{n'} = 8.37563694823693)

The differences between $X_{n'}$ & $X_n$ and $Z_{n'}$ & $Z_n$ are as follows:

X difference = -0.14946446105604
Z difference = -0.0850703082029192

My method is calculating the point ($P_{n'}$) on the "N" coordinate system as being to the left of and below the original ($P_n$), so I was wondering what I'm missing as I've tried changing some of the rotation matrices by swapping over the -sin and sin values but that doesn't help, so all I can think of is that I've made an error with the steps in my method.

Comment: *VB6*?! Yikes! You sure you don't want to move up in technology and press it into runny clay tablets with a reed stylus instead?

Comment: It is really hard to interpret your description, because you keep using names that do not match the symbology, and give shorthand descriptions that are meaningless to someone who isn't already familiar with your problem (i.e., your entire audience). . "$(X, Y, Z)$ does not represent a *plane*. Do you mean "coordinate system"? Exactly how is "$(X_N, Y_N, Z_N)$" perpendicular to the helix curve? What is $\theta$? The "Normal Plane Point" is what? What is the "Component Lead"? The axial plane point is the result of what? Your matrices are $3 \times 2$. What 2D vectors do they act on?

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is an existing application that I have to maintain, so it has to be in VB6 for now (there are plans to upgrade it, but that's in the future after I fix this issue).

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am going from the documentation left by the person who did the job before me and it's been about 25 years since I last worked with a lot of maths to this level. I'll make some edits to my original text and see if I can clear it up more.